# Matlab: correlation number

Tags: matlab, vector, correlation

I have a 2 vectors of numbers of either 1 or -1. What are the standard tools on Matlab that would help me calculate a correlation number between the two vectors? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CORRCOEF](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/corrcoef.html) function is what you're looking for:

```
R = corrcoef(vector1(:),vector2(:));  %# Returns a 2-by-2 matrix of
                                      %#   correlation coefficients
```

If you have the [Statistics Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/), you may also want to check out the function [CORR](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/corr.html):

```
RHO = corr(vector1(:),vector2(:));  %# Returns the linear correlation coefficient
                                    %#   (default is a Pearson correlation)
```

Comment: And these work for non-continuous data as well? I'm not an expert on correlation, but the fact that his data is binary raises a flag in my head.

Comment: Here's my answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phi_coefficient
"In statistics, the phi coefficient φ or rφ is a measure of association for two binary variables. This measure is similar to the Pearson correlation coefficient in its interpretation. In fact, a Pearson correlation coefficient estimated for two binary variables will return the phi coefficient.[1] "

Answer (score 3):

The corr function in matlab would switch to Phi-coefficient if it sees binary data.

Comment: Can you please link to the source?

Comment: By, "if it sees binary data", do you mean "if it sees a matrix of type 'logical'" or "if it sees a real matrix with two unique values" (or both)?